# c++ design pattern for input multiplexing?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have to read and process data synchronously in my program from several sources, like the following:

```
main
...
while(true)  {
dataSample1 = readInput1...
processData(dataSample1) 
....
dataSample2 = readInput2...
processData(dataSample2) 
}
```

Each readInput is implemented in separate component to deal with different nature of inputs (e.g. sockets, usb port, etc. ), but the format for data samples is the same. The problem is that both readInput and processData are blocking, so I have to come up with solution to multiplex reading of inputs for "processData". Does this problem correspond to "reactor" or "proactor" pattern? Are there frameworks to help with implementation without moving each "readInput" into separate thread? 
Thanks...

Comment: You're thinking in the right direction, but your explanation is confusing.  If multiple samples come from one source, should those all be processed immediately, or does each need to wait for a paired sample from the other source?

Comment: Also, what are your reasons for avoiding threading?

Comment: I confess my description is confusing in the sense that i am talking about de- multiplexing of inputs, the inputs are coming from different sources. My reasons for avoiding threading: performance. I'd like to avoid 10 separate threads for 10 separate low bitrate inputs, i think most of cpu time in this situation would be wasted for switching between threads...

Comment: Is your program that performance-sensitive that a couple thousand nanoseconds for a context switch is going to be a problem? How many (potential) threads are we talking about?

Comment: I did something like this before, with one thread reading a dozen sources and doing no processing, just enqueuing incoming messages.  Then another thread dequeued and processed them.  This made sure that messages couldn't be reordered by more than a couple microseconds.  You don't need a thread per source, just two total, and they probably won't share a core -- a modern multicore system will schedule those two threads on two different cores.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to rewrite/reconfigure the various `readInput` functions to become non-blocking?  If not, separate threads (maybe even separate processes) are the only way to have them running in parallel.  If yes, then a reactor pattern can help you trigger the right processing when each input arrives.

Comment: i am not sure that making "readInput" unblocking is a solution as "processInput" is also blocking ( takes 10-100 msecs). That means inputs will be processed in order of loop, not as new data becomes available. Looks to me as for 10 different inputs i need 10 different "producers" to buffer data for consumption by "processData". Does that correspond to "reactor"?

Comment: @user: Data can't be processed as it becomes available if the computer is busy.  When it's idle, you can process as it becomes available.  Is this an issue of processing order for data received while busy?